# Column being indexed - cannot create site from custom template

Tags: managed-metadata, site-template, choice-field, multiple-values, indexed-column

I created several content types in the content type hub. Next, I have created a site out of the default team site with several document libraries and lists on my site which utilize these content types published from the hub.

I have created a site template out of my site and was able to successfully use it for the new site creation.

Now there is a request to change 4 fields. 3 which are managed metadata should be changed from single choice to multiple choice, and 1 which was a single choice field to multiple choice field. After implementing changes successfully in the CT hub, I republished the content types and they were nicely picked by the document libraries and the lists in my site.

Next, I needed a new site template. I created it, but when I wanted to make a new site using that template it failed with the following error message:

> Cannot change this column to allow multiple values because it is
>   currently being indexed.

I am not sure which of the column(s) are causing the problems. I know that the indexing won't work on the multiple choice fields, but how do I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the content type hub is a red herring here - I suspect you have an index set on one of those altered columns.  Go to List settings for the lists affected and click "Indexed Columns" below the Columns section.  Find the offending indexes and remove them.  Then create a new template and try to spin up a new site with the new template.